# Go server with 2 cpus

Tags: go, server, grpc, go-server

I'm building a GRPC server in GO and I want increase its performance. I've increased my machine and put 2CPUS in order to make it better but I noticed that my server doesn't use all cpu cores and I couldn't find a way to fix it (I've run some tests to make the server worker harder). It seems like my server uses 1 cpu a lot and the other not. My load average stay above 1 what means that my server is full of requests but when I see the performance in netdata there's only one CPU working.

This is my grpc code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "log"
    "net"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/reflection"
    pb "teste/prototeste"

)
func (s *server) Test(ctx context.Context, n *pb.TestRequest)      (*pb.TestReply, error){
    return &pb.TestReply{Message: n.Name}, nil
}

type server struct{}

const (
    port = ":50051"
)

func main(){

    numOfCores := runtime.NumCPU()
    fmt.Println(numOfCores)
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numOfCores)
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    // Register reflection service on gRPC server.
    reflection.Register(s)

    s.Serve(lis)

}
```

Notice that in Serve function there's a goroutine that allow the server accept multiple requests in parallel.

[API reference grpc in go](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc)

[This is my cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76OfE.png)

Any tips to how to solve this and make my server use 2 cpus?

Comment: Are you using Docker? A virtual machine? Launching it through a systemd unit with CPUAffinity set? Maybe your server has CPUAffinity set to 1 or 2 CPUs in the user.slice. Maybe your OS kernel is using some kind of setting that drives network traffic to a CPU per connection hash and you're only testing from one IP. . .

Comment: I run many tests with 1 and 2 differents IPs and the result was the same. I'm using a virtual machine. What is this CPUAffinity? I didn't know about this.

Comment: Ah, and the server is running in a linux centos

Comment: If you're running in a virtual machine, how many CPU's did you configure the virtual machine to use?

Comment: Some information about packet steering which might apply https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt

Comment: I've configured 2 CPUs and the result was the same as 1 CPU

Comment: I saw my process affinity and it gives me: "pid 31255's current affinity list: 0,1" What means it can run in one of my 2 CPUs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gRPC, each server handler runs in its own goroutine.  From there it is up to the Go scheduler to determine what CPUs to schedule them on.  Depending on what your server handlers are doing, system load, etc, it's possible they could all end up scheduled on the same CPU.